# simple_form problems with login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

first off I'm very new to rails - I'm playing about with a little log in application had it all working and decided to try out simple form - however I can't get my log in form to work with the gem.

**Here is what I had and had working;**

```
<h2>Log In</h2>

<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>

  <p><%= link_to "Forgotten Password?", new_password_reset_path %></p>

  <div class="field">
    <%= check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, params[:remember_me] %>
    <%= label_tag :remember_me %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Log In" %></div>

<% end %>
```

**And here is what I tried to change it to using simple form.**

```
<h2>Log In</h2>

<%= simple_form_for :sessions, :url => sessions_path, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :email, :required =>false, :label => 'Email Address',:placeholder => 'Email Address' %>

    <%= f.input :password, :required =>false, :label => 'Password',:placeholder => 'Password' %>

  <label class="checkbox">
    <%= check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, params[:remember_me] %>
    Remember me
  </label>

  <p>
    <%= link_to "Forgotten Password?", new_password_reset_path %>
  </p>


  <%= f.button :submit "Login" %>

<% end %>
```

This seems to work okay until I try to log in - **when I log in it is always displaying my invalid username and password message** - I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Many thanks to Zabba for pointing me in the right direction;

My second method works;

```
<%= simple_form_for :sessions, :url => sessions_path, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |f| %>

        <%= f.input :email, :required =>false, :label => 'Email Address',:placeholder => 'Email Address' %>

        <%= f.input :password, :required =>false, :label => 'Password',:placeholder => 'Password' %>

      <label class="checkbox">
        <%= check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, params[:remember_me] %>
        Remember me
      </label>

      <p>
        <%= link_to "Forgotten Password?", new_password_reset_path %>
      </p>


      <%= f.button :submit "Login" %>

    <% end %>
```

**However I failed to update my controller so where I had;**

```
  def create 
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        ...
  end
```

**I had to update to;**

```
  def create 
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:sessions][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
        ...
  end
```

Thanks Zabba!

Answer (score 2):

In case 1, you are probably receiving params: `{ :email => '...', ....}` and in case 2, `:sessions => { :email => '...', ....}`

Check params.inspect

Comment: I had it as <%=simple_form_for sessions_path, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |f| %> --- but got the error Routing Error 
No route matches [POST] "/login" - Any suggestions?

Comment: Got it working! Thanks for the point in the right direction @Zabba - If anyones interested I'll post the answer in 8 hours when it allows me to! :)