# Basic User Authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, simple-form

I'm working on implementing some basic user authentication in Rails 4, following this article

http://nycda.com/blog/basic-user-authentication-model-in-rails-4/

Instead of using the ERB form provided, I recreated (at least I thought I did) the process with simple_form, and the query being passed when I try and log in is this:

```
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` IS NULL  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

when I tried with the ERB example using form_tag instead of simple_form, the process worked fine. Here are the two forms for comparison:

My form (converted from HAML to ERB)

```
<%= simple_form_for :sessions, :url => log_in_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>

    <%= f.button :submit, 'Login' %>
```

From the article above:

```
<%= form_tag log_in_path do %>
  <%= label_tag :email %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  <%= label_tag :password %>
  <%= password_field_tag :password %>

  <%= submit_tag "Log in" %>  
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this article: [simple_form problems with login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202590/simple-form-problems-with-login)

had to update the create action of the sessions controller.

this:

```
@user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
```

became this:

```
@user = User.authenticate(params[:sessions][:email], params[:sessions][:password])
```

Works like a charm now!